# How to implement a pythonic line continuation read

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, file

I am trying to implement a python script to read and extract lines from an ASCII text file. This seems to be a rather easy thing, however I ended up with an issue which I can't resolve myself.
The file I am trying to read contains test and some of the lines 
begin with `*tr999`. This pattern can have either big or small letters and the number of digits and the presence of the `*` is optional. The asterisk can also be before and after. This signal keyword is followed by numbers, either int or folat.  To catch the signal, I use a python regexp expression

```
re.search("[*]{0,1}[Tt][Rr][0-9]{1,5}[*]{0,1}",line)
```

The text file looks like this

```
tr10* 1 2 3 22 1 1 13 12 33 33 33
*Tr20 12 22 -1 2  2 2 5 5 5 6 6 6 77
Tr20 1 1 1 &
           2 0 0
           1 1 1
           2 2 2
c that is a comment and below is the problem case '&' is missing
*tr22221 2 2 2
         1 1 1
         2 2 2
```

The code I wrote can't catch the last case. Where the continue line signal `&` is missing. The use of `&` to continue line is optional and can be replaced by a number of white spaces at the begging of the continued  line .

The code I wrote is

```
import sys

fp=open(sys.argv[1],'r')
import re 

# get the integers only
def loop_conv(string):
        conv=[]
        for i in string.split(" "):
            try:
                conv.append(float(i))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        return conv

# extract the information
def extract_trans_card(line,fp):
            extracted=False
            if len(line)>2 and not re.search("[cC]",line.split()[0]) and re.search("[*]{0,1}[Tt][Rr][0-9]{1,5}[*]{0,1}",line) :
                extracted=True
                trans_card=[]
                trans_card.append(line.split()[0])
                line_old=line
   # this part here is because after the read signal,
   # data to be extracted might be on the same line             
                for val in loop_conv(line):
                        trans_card.append(val)
# this part here fails. I am not able to catch the case '&' missing.
# i tried to peek the next line with seek() but it i got a system error. 
# the idea is to loop until i have a continue line case  
                while (re.search("^(\s){5,60}",line) or re.search("[&$]",line_old)) and len(trans_card) <13:

                    line=fp.readline()
                    for val in loop_conv(line):
                        trans_card.append(val)
                    line_old=line


                #print('M',trans_card)
                print('value',trans_card)
                trans_card=[]
            return extracted 



# read the file with a loop
for line in fp:
        if not extract_trans_card(line,fp) :
            print(line,end='')
```

The output is:

```
value ['tr10*', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 22.0, 1.0, 1.0, 13.0, 12.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0]
value ['*Tr20', 12.0, 22.0, -1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 77.0]
value ['Tr20', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
    c that is a comment and below is the problem case '&' is missing
value ['*tr22221', 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
             1 1 1
             2 2 2
```

The last line is the problem. Since the `1 1 1` and `2 2 2` get ignored and are just echoed.
This problem looks similar to how python does continue line. Either by spaces or by using `&`. 
I hope someone will help we with this and would point the proper manner to do this problem

Comment: Your first regular expression, **re.search("[\*]{0,1}[Tt][Rr][0-9]{1,5}[\*]{0,1}",line)** was not correct. It will match, for example, the line '  tr12  ' because you made '*' optional at both the beginning and the end and you are not forcing the match to happen at the beginning of the line. The regular expression is also overly complicated. Try: **re.match("\\*tr\d{1,5}|tr\d{1,5}\\*",line, re.IGNORECASE)**

Comment: I have a different regular expression, namely `re.search("[*]{0,1}[Tt][Rr][0-9]{1,5}[*]{0,1}",line)` it will match an asterisk if it would appear at both the beginning and at the end. This is actually wanted.

Comment: It will also match a line that contains no asterisk because [\*]{0,1} allows it be missing altogether, but it also allows it to be present at both ends, too. I assumed that it must be present either at the beginning or the end (I was wrong) but not both (was I wrong?). And the sequences \*tr123 or tr123\*, assuming the asterisk was present, could be anywhere within the line, not just at the beginning. **re.match** forces the search to be at the beginning of the line as would a '^' as the first character of your regular expression.

Comment: The regexp is doing fine. The problem is at a different place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code workflow is when the continue line signal is optional, it will be hard to detect the last line associated with the **current** *trans_card* without messing up with the next *trans_card*.

Since the beginning (header) of a trans_card can be found with `re.search(r"[*]?[Tt][Rr][0-9]{1,5}[*]?"`, it would be easier to process the **previous** trans_card whenever this **header** pattern is detected.

Below is a sample code which I roughly copied from your code logic and saved the resulting trans_card into a list of lists:

```
import sys
import re

# get the floats only from line, copied from your code
def loop_conv(string):
    conv=[]
    for i in string.split(" "):
      try:
        conv.append(float(i))
      except ValueError:
        pass
    return conv

# set previous trans_card with non-EMPTY vals list
def set_prev_trans_card(card, vals):
    if len(vals):
        card.append(vals)
        #print ('value: {}'.format(vals))

# below new code logic:
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fp:
    trans_card = []

    # a list to save items retrieved from lines associated with the same trans_card
    values = []

    # set up a flag to identify header
    is_header = 0

    for line in fp:
        # if line is a comment, then skip it 
        if re.search("[cC]",line.split()[0]):
            #print(line, end='')
            continue

        # if line is a header, append the existing values[] (from the previous trans_card) 
        # list to trans_card[] and then reset values[]
        if len(line)>2 and re.search(r"[*]?[Tt][Rr][0-9]{1,5}[*]?", line):
            # append values[] to trans_card
            set_prev_trans_card(trans_card, values)

            # reset values[] to the first \S+ on the header 
            values = [ line.split()[0] ]

            # set is_header flag to 1
            is_header = 1

        # if line ends with &\n, then concatenate the next lines
        while line.endswith('&\n'):
            line += ' ' + fp.readline()

        # add all numbers(floats) from header or lines starts with 5-60 white-spaces into the values[] list, and reset is_header flag to 0
        if is_header or re.search("^(\s){5,60}",line):
            values.extend(loop_conv(line))
            is_header = 0

    # append the last values[] to trans_card
    set_prev_trans_card(trans_card, values)

for v in trans_card:
    print ('value: {}'.format(v))
```

output is:

```
value: ['tr10*', 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 22.0, 1.0, 1.0, 13.0, 12.0, 33.0, 33.0, 33.0]
value: ['*Tr20', 12.0, 22.0, -1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 77.0]
value: ['Tr20', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
value: ['*tr22221', 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0]
```

**Note:** I skipped the condition of `len(trans_card) <13` in your code, thought it's just used to prevent infinite while loop. if not, it should be easy to add into the above example code.

BTW. you might want to add `^` to patterns of comment and header so that they only match the beginning of strings instead of anywhere in the searching strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The idea behind the logic, is that I would like to have the code inside a subroutine. I have to call it at few places in the main code. I could copy paste the same lines few times, but this would make it look like a hastily packed suitcase.

Comment: @AlexanderCska, do you want a subroutine `extract_trans_card(line, fp)` and exactly with the same arguments? if not, you can wrap up the `for` loop into a subroutine. If you insist the subroutine must be feed by line, will have to add one more argument like `prev_line`, since there is no easy way to identify the end of block while avoiding reading into the next trans_card block.

Comment: you are correct if it is inside a subroutine, one has to peek the next line or use a global variable, which retains it's value. I did an implementation with `seek()` and `tell()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Pythonic way of processing a file (actually anything that is iterable where the **next()** item returns a string, possibly ending in a newline character or not) where continuation can be designated by '&' in the last column of the current "record" (Python actually uses '\') or a space character in the next "record":

```
import re


def read_lines_with_continue(iter):
    """This function is passed an interator where each iteration returns the next line.
       This function processes logical continuations consisting of lines that end with '&' or lines
       that begin a space."""

    next_line = ''
    saw_continue = True
    for line in iter:
        # get rid of any trailing '&'
        edited_line = re.sub(r'&$', '', line)
        if saw_continue:
            next_line += edited_line
            saw_continue = False
        elif line[0] == ' ':
            next_line += edited_line
        elif next_line != '':
            yield next_line
            next_line = edited_line
        if line != edited_line:
            saw_continue = True
    if next_line != '':
        yield next_line


lines = [
    '1abc',
    '2def&',
    'ghi',
    ' xyz',
    ' ver&',
    'jkl',
    '3aaa',
    '4xxx',
    ' yyy'
]


# instead of passing a list, you could also pass a file
for l in read_lines_with_continue(lines):
    print(l)

1abc
2defghi xyz verjkl
3aaa
4xxx yyy
```

Comment: This is not really what I am looking for.